# Why export to CSV only returns URLs but not text with Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to get the Urls (lnk) and the paragraphs (txt) extract form python script below into a csv with pandas.

For some reason the generated csv returns the headers (lnk and txt) and the Urls only, but not the corresponding paragraphs.
The CSV file returns currently that

```
lnk    | txt
url 1  | 
url 2  |
```

What I need would be

```
lnk    | txt
url 1  | text 1
url 2  | text 2
```

But both the Urls and the paragraphs do get printed in the cmd console.

Why doesn't the paragraphs get exported into the csv as well?
What would be a working fix to this problem? thanks.

(sorry for the long code, I'm new to Python)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url_txt = []


#GET TEXT
def getPageText(url):
    # given a url, get page content
    data = urlopen(url).read()
    # parse as html structured document
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    # kill javascript content
    for s in soup(["script", "style"]):
        s.replaceWith('')
    #remove the text from this class
    soup.find('p', {"class":"tiny-off"}).decompose()
    #remove the text from this div id
    soup.find('div', id = 'action-bar-top').decompose()
    #remove the text from this div id
    soup.find('div', id = 'main-content-sidebar').decompose()
    #remove the text from this class
    soup.find('div', {"class":"legal"}).decompose()
    #get the 1st paragraph (which is a link)
    for p in soup.find_all('p')[0]:
        lnk = p.get_text()
        print(lnk)
    #remove the 1st paragraph (the link) from the following combined paragraphs
    soup.find('p', id = 'current_url').decompose()
    #extract all paragraphs save the 1st (the link)
    for p in soup.find_all('p'):
        txt = p.get_text().replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
        print(txt)
    
    # Compiling the info
    lnktxt_data = [lnk, txt]

    # Append the info to the complete dataset
    url_txt.append(lnktxt_data)
    
#Get text from multiple urls    
def main():
    urls = [
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400153/how-to-export-pandas-dataframe-into-csv-file',       #dummy page
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716762/how-to-join-newlines-into-a-paragraph-in-python'     #dummy page
    ]
    txt = [getPageText(url) for url in urls]
    for t in txt:
        print(t)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
    
#FRAME DATA
# Making the dataframe
url_txt = pd.DataFrame(url_txt, columns = ['lnk', 'txt'])
 
url_txt.head()
    
#CREATE A FILE
# Save as CSV File
url_txt.to_csv('url_txt.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simpler way that's working (with room for improvement),
with help from those two previous answers

[How to join newlines into a paragraph in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52717692/10789707)

[How to scrape web news and combine paragraphs into each article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889643/10789707)

Please let me know below how you would improve it if you find a better way.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


#GET TEXT
def getPageText(url):
    # given a url, get page content
    data = urlopen(url).read()
    # parse as html structured document
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    # kill javascript content
    for s in soup(["script", "style"]):
        s.replaceWith('')
    #
    for p in soup.find_all('p')[1]:
        lnk = p.get_text()
        print(lnk)
    #
    # find body and extract text
    p = soup.find("div", attrs={'class': 'article-content retro-folders'})
    p.append(p.get_text())
    x = p.text
    y = x.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
    print(y)
    

    # Compiling the info
    lnktxt_data = [lnk, y]

    # Append the info to the complete dataset
    url_txt.append(lnktxt_data)


url_txt = []


#Get text from multiple urls    
def main():
    urls = [
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400153/how-to-export-pandas-dataframe-into-csv-file',       #dummy page
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716762/how-to-join-newlines-into-a-paragraph-in-python'     #dummy page
    ]
    txt = [getPageText(url) for url in urls]
    for t in txt:
        print(t)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
    
#FRAME DATA
# Making the dataframe
url_txt = pd.DataFrame(url_txt, columns = ['lnk', 'y'])
 
url_txt.head()
    
#CREATE A FILE
# Save as CSV File
url_txt.to_csv('url_txt.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: New script with delays and user-agent version: https://web.archive.org/web/20220219104129/https://pastebin.com/3GLRG4rM